# How do I check if an array exists in fish?

Tags: arrays, shell, fish

The method I'm currently using seems to be working alright in this particular case, but when I was first searching around for answers I couldn't find any questions regarding this. So, an example of how I'm checking arrays currently:

```sh
# An example array, $array_1, with three items.
set -l array_1 "item_1" "item_2" "item_3"
# How I'm checking if an array exists.
if test -n "$array_1"
  echo "The array exists."
end
# How I'm checking if an array doesn't exist.
if test -z "$array_2"
  echo "The array does not exist."
end
# How I'm checking if an array element exists.
if test -n "$array_1[2]"
  echo "Item 2 from the array_1 exists."
end
```

I don't know if this is the suggested methods of checking arrays, but at the moment those methods are working in my particular cases. Is there any case in which these methods would break? And, does anyone know of a better way to achieve these checks that would be considered best practices?

Any and all input is appreciated. Hopefully, the answers to this question will help anyone else in the future looking into working with arrays in the fish shell.

Comment: @chepner gave the correct answer but I wanted to propose a thought experiment. After `set array_1 a "" c` is `test -n "$array_1[2]"` true or false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `set -q`.

```
if set -q array_1
    echo "array_1 exists"
end

if set -q array_1[2]
    echo "Item 2 from array_1 exists
end
```

Comment: Just a small clarification to @chepner's answer. Fish does not have sparse arrays so his second example is equivalent to `if test (count $array_1) '>=' 2`. I prefer the `set -q` solution provided by @chepner but sometimes `count` is what you need. Also, another subtle point involves omitting the dollar-sign when using `set -q` -- this frequently confuses new fish users.

Comment: Thanks. Excellent information you guys. I wasn't really aware of the `-q` option. Thank you both again for providing info!